# How to create images from iso for KVM?

Tags: iso, kvm-virtualization, openstack

Hi all :) I want to create a KVM image from an existing iso file (for glance on OpenStack), but I didn't find how to do it. Can you help me please?

Comment: Normally you would just boot the iso with KVM.

Comment: I try it but it didn't work. I must have an existing KVM image to add it to Glance and run it with nova compute.

Comment: KVM will boot most any live iso image. Are you wanting to create a custom iso ? Clone installations ?

Comment: I want to create a pre-installed disk images from iso file.

Comment: So boot the image, install from the image, and clone the resulting hard disk. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests

Comment: Question doesn't make sense; an iso file *is* an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a VM with a size (6G below) (it will be small until the install is done into it)

```
qemu-img create myvm.img -f qcow2 6G
```

Then install the iso into your vm

```
kvm -m 750 -cdrom ${PWD}/whatever.iso -boot d myvm.img
```

And run it in 990M of memory:

```
kvm -m 990 myvm.img
```

Comment: ubfan, could you review other answer below?

Answer (score 3):

This isn’t correct. This is for booting a KVM instance using an image that was created and a foreign ISO.

Maybe something similar to this in order to "convert" an ISO to an qcow2 image. I might be confused about the OP. I was looking to convert an ISO to qcow2.

Your instructions seem right to boot an ISO for an blank qcow2 disk image for a hard drive for 6G.

```
qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2 eProx-Clover.iso eProx-Clover.qcow2
```

(but it has to flagged as a bootable ISO in order to boot with `-d`.)

Comment: The question is not all that clear, and the comments add some additional inconsistencies, but the poster is not just trying to convert an ISO to something. glance is used to register/store kvm images, so create the KVM image by installing the ISO, (call this the "pre-install" image?), run it and install any additional packages, then register/store it with glance.  My answer stopped at the last "run" step, since the poster didn't specify what if any additional packages they wanted.

Comment: This is the solution if your ISO simply doesn't boot and you know it's a bootable ISO.