# Convert .iso to .qcow2

Tags: networking, virtualization, 20.04, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have ubuntu20.04 lts iso file downloaded from ubuntu website. Can you please guide to convert the iso file into qcow2 file. For instance I need the file ubuntu.qcow2 to be made from ubuntu.iso

Comment: Refer to [an existing question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293294/how-to-create-images-from-iso-for-kvm) which may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange, you need to use the iso file for one proposal and qcow2 for another one:

- iso for cdrom images
- qcow2 for harddrive images

Why do you want to convert it?